# Adding Custom JSON-LD Scripts to Kentico Page Types

Tags: search, kentico, schema.org, json-ld

We are interested in adding a custom script using JSON-LD and Schema.org to the head of our Kentico portal engine site pages (v11). We would like to use this to assist with our custom search crawler to categorize, filter, and index our pages.

Below is an example of the script that would be on one of our "Product" pages.  However, this script will vary based on the page type (Event, generic page, etc.). Is there a recommended way to add this script automatically with the appropriate data to each of our pages?  Should we use a transformation for each page type?  Or a custom module or webpart?

````
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Test Product",
  "image": "https://www.test.com/uploads/2010/10/testproduct.png",
  "description": "This is a description for the test product.",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Test Thing"
  }
}
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom webpart.

The webpart should utilise data from the Current Document, and generate the appropriate JSON-LD structured data snippet based on the Page Type.  Or you could have multiples webparts - one for each Page Type.